# Does an Angular client UI run entirely in the browser

Tags: angular

Encountered some Angular developers who were discussing Angular's server side code. 
This surprised me.

Does Angular have server side code?

I was under the impression that all the code ( libraries, routing, components) all of it, is downloaded to the client.

My question is explicitly this :   **As you navigate through different routes, controllers, etc. in an Angular application,  does the browser make repeated calls to the node web server.**

Webapi calls are obviously calls to some server somewhere. That's not part of this question.

My impression from the limited amount of work I have done in angular(v8) is that it is entirely browser side.

This may be a simple question, but I have been unable to find a definitive answer.

Comment: *Does an Angular client UI run entirely in the browser* -- Yes.

Comment: I'm guessing the conversation you overheard related to [server side rendering](https://angular.io/guide/universal) for "Angular Universal" apps, which is a bit different.

Comment: @NicholasK - you confirm my assumption. Put this in answer form and I will accept it and upvote it. Thank you

Comment: @Chris W.    - oddly enough , no.  The discussion was one concerning the merits of Angular vs 'The World' and their opinion of the Angular server side code was not a high opinion.  This put me in a bit of a tailspin, but couldn't point to any article on the web that said explicitly that the client was essentially self contained once it was downloaded. (as opposed to an asp.net client which  typically combines calls for UI & data)

Answer (score 1):

> Does an Angular client UI run entirely in the browser

Yes. The browser downloads the required bundles when the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

Both Angular and React have related projects that enabled Server-Side Rendering (SSR) for these Single Page Application (SPA) frameworks. For Angular, the project is called [Angular-Universal.](https://angular.io/guide/universal)

In this scenario, there is server-side NodeJs code that can recognize Angular routes and then render that route completely before it sends it downstream to the browser. The browser can then render the page without needing the SPA (javascript) code, after which it can then start the SPA.

Comment: Rynes. Thank you for the response.  Not knowing enough to ask a clear question up front...   let me clarify... I think the existence of SSR implies that NON SSR Angular ( regular Angular ) happens all on the client side. Agree?

Comment: I agree with that

Answer (score 1):

**As you navigate through different routes, controllers, etc. in an Angular application, does the browser make repeated calls to the node web server.**

The answer is in fact yes. 
Try stopping the ng serve process and see what happens. 
Take a look at DevControls network tab as you navigate the app.

My question was bolded, and is not ambiguously worded.  The angular front end in fact makes repeated calls to the web server to download components.

This is surprising to me, but seems fairly clear given my observations.

I believe that these are merely downloads. Angular does not download the entire app when you hit the homepage. 
I still contest the conversation I overheard that there is server side code 'running'. I have encountered nothing to support that. But that's another question...

Comment: With respect to lazy loaded modules, then yes you are right. But for eagerly loaded modules, then stopping `ng serve` would not have any impact on the application as all the modules would have been downloaded by the browser initially.